# OpenCV transform key points into pixel coordinates

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I'm trying to extract the **pixel coordinates** from a given `cv::KeyPoint`. This class has a variable named `pt` of type `cv::Point2f` which is simply a tuple containing two *floats*.

I'm not sure casting the `cv::Point2f` to `cv::Point2i` works since I cannot find in the docs what are these float numbers representing.

I'm trying to do this in **python**, but I can't find a proper **OpenCV 3** documentation for python neither.

My code:

```
import cv2

feature_detector = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()
key_points = feature_detector.detect(img, None)

# this is a list of float tuples e.g. (100.3224, 451.2334)
float_coordinates = list(map(lambda key_point: key_point.pt))  

# pixel_coordinates = ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Looks like `cv::Point2f` are sub-pixel coordinates. Just rounding the **floats** to the nearest **ints** should work just fine.

There's an OpenCV function that already does this called  [cv::cvRound](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#ga085eca238176984a0b72df2818598d85).

This is in fact what OpenCV does in its function `cv::_drawKeypoint` in [/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp)